# LWC Extending LightningTreeGrid does not render

Tags: lightning-web-components

I would like add functionality to the Lightning Tree Grid component.

Starting with a base component of:

```
import LightningTreeGrid from 'lightning/treeGrid';

export default class CustomTreeGrid extends LightningTreeGrid {}
```

And referencing the component as

```
<c-custom-tree-grid
    data={data}
    columns={columns}
    key-field="Id"
    expanded-rows={currentExpanded}
    onrowaction={handleRowAction}
    selected-rows={selectedRows}
    hide-checkbox-column="true"
></c-custom-tree-grid>
```

I would expect this to render a normal Tree Grid, but instead nothing is rendered at all. Walking through the component life cycle tells me that all the attributes are being correctly set, and the constructor on the actual LightningTreeGrid is being called properly.

The one oddity I noticed is that the rendered CustomTreeGrid javascript's template function is blank.

```
(function() {
    const {$A, aura, Sfdc, sforce} = {};

    return function (lwc, LightningTreeGrid) {

        function tmpl($api, $cmp, $slotset, $ctx) {
        return [];
        }

        var _tmpl = lwc.registerTemplate(tmpl);
        tmpl.stylesheets = [];
        tmpl.stylesheetTokens = {
        hostAttribute: "c-customTreeGrid_customTreeGrid-host",
        shadowAttribute: "c-customTreeGrid_customTreeGrid"
        };

        class CustomTreeGrid extends LightningTreeGrid {}

        var customTreeGrid = lwc.registerComponent(CustomTreeGrid, {
        tmpl: _tmpl
        });

        return customTreeGrid;

    }

}())
```

[Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/Dulcc42an/2/edit) is a playground demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Hello @SethBoyd it seems that your playground is correct, I have working example in my project, where I extend RadioGroup, but it doesn't work in Playground. Did you try your option without .HTML file in real project?

Answer (score 2):

I am not a Javascript wizard but will try to answer what I noticed.

You are extending `LightningTreeGrid`  as

`export default class CustomTreeGrid extends LightningTreeGrid {}`

This only extends the Javascript of `LightningTreeGrid`, but does not extends the markup. Now this means you can access all methods and attributes of `LightningTreeGrid` class in `CustomTreeGrid` .

Now in your LWC component `CustomTreeGrid` the html markup is blank, thus it does not know you intend to build a `lightning-tree-grid` . It only means you intend to use JS method from `LightningTreeGrid`

Solution: Add markup of `lightning-tree-grid` in `CustomTreeGrid` html.

CustomTreeGrid.html :

```
<template>
    <lightning-tree-grid                   
                columns={columns}
                data={data}               
                key-field={keyField}
            ></lightning-tree-grid>
</template>
```

CustomTreeGrid.js :

```
import LightningTreeGrid from 'lightning/treeGrid';
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';

export default class CustomTreeGrid extends LightningTreeGrid {
    @api data;
    @api columns;
    @api keyField;

}
```

Playground Link : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/Dulcc42an/3/edit

Comment: I took the syntax from the Create Custom Data Types section of the [Data Table documentation] (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation#creating-custom-data-types) which correctly renders a Datatable even without an html template. This method will not give me access to the table contained in the Tree Grid component, which is what I need.

Comment: @SethBoyd I tried but couldnt do it, can you provide playground example?

Comment: Sure. Here is an example: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/sYMrJDVtZ/1/edit

Comment: Also got this working - but unfortunately all related handlers need to be taken with the custom type as well... kinda painful.

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:treeGrid/documentation, I can't see if lightning has exported treeGrid likewise LightningDataTable.
Thanks